# can i have docker container with cuda 8 if my host has cuda 9

Tags: docker, cuda

I have GPU system on which CUDA 9 is installed. I need a separate environment with CUDA 8. So can I create a docker container having CUDA 8 in the same host? or the host needs to have CUDA 8 also?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to have CUDA 8 in your host. because docker has its own kernel.

for install CUDA 8 with docker you can copy this Docker File.

https://gitlab.com/nvidia/cuda/blob/centos6/8.0/runtime/Dockerfile

after you can run this command in the same directory as your Dockerfile :

```
docker build  -t img-cuda8 .
```

after you run it by this CMD

```
docker run -itd my-cuda -d img-cuda8
```